# React Parent Function Called from Child Component does not Update State?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-component, react-state

I'm stuck on having my child component: `ChildButton` call its parent component: `ParentTable`'s function that contains a "setState", to then refresh or update the table itself (in the parent).

I am passing a `getData` function from the parent to the child through props. On button click in the child - call a function to; close a dialog, do a PUT on a mock api datastore, then call the `getData` function. The getData function does a GET from the api and does a setState on "apiData". Problem is the data is not updating in the parent table even though the getData function is being called.. Don't state changes cause a reload? Code below:

`ParentTable.jsx`

```
export default function ParentTable() {
    **const [apiData, setAPIData] = useState([]);**

    const getData = () => {
        axios.get(`https://blah.mockapi.io/fakeData`)
            .then((getData) => {
                **setAPIData**(getData.data);
            })
        console.log('getData'); // fires on child button click
        }

    return (
        <Table..
            <Table.Body>
                {**apiData**.map((obj) => {
                    <Table.Cell>bunch of data from the obj..
                    <Table.Cell><ChildButton **getData={getData}**</Table.Cell>
                    
        ... />../>../>
    )
}

export default ParentTable;
```

`ChildButton.jsx`

```
const ChildButton = ({getData, ...}) => {
    function handleClose() {
        setOpen(false)
        axios.put(`https://blah.mockapi.io/fakeData/${id}`, {
            ...
        })
        **getData()**

    }

    return (
        <Button onClick={handleClose} ...>
            Update
        </Button>
    )
}

export default ChildButton;
```

Long story short - why is my change of state in the Parent Component not updating it's table data?

Comment: One way to check is putting a `console.log()` inside your `.then()` and seeing if the API call is actually doing something. Try to log something right above the `setState` and let us know

Comment: Hey Tushar, adding a `console.log(getData.data)` inside the then, above the setApiData returns the object but with the OLD data..

Comment: That means your API is not returning the OLD data right. Also, please name your functions differently than your objects. Will cause confusion

Comment: what names are causing confusion? Also, i think this might be a race condition like you mention.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Axios.put returns a promise and you are not waiting for the response. Invoke the getData function inside the .then function or use async await:

```
 axios.put(`https://blah.mockapi.io/fakeData/${id}`, {
            ...
        }).then(() => **getData()**)
```